# Simulate KeyboardInterrupt with fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric

How do I fire a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with fabric, in other words is it possible to trigger KeyboardInterrupt manually via bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctrl+c` generates a SIGINT signal.

You can send a signal with `kill -SIGINT pid` where `pid` is the process id. you wish to signal.  `kill` is a Bash built-in.